# Return Not Rendering when setting Object = [ ], works when setting Object = {}

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am formating my data so that it looks like  `results`

When I use set `var results = {}` the result is outputting in the render however if set `var results = []` to an array it is NOT returned to the render. I can see it in the console log but not on render.

Here is a CodeSandBox to play around with

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-fire-x52qb

```
var results = {}

dates.forEach(function(item) {
  var arrayOfEvents = [];

  arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(value) {
    if (item === value.info.startDate) {
      // Found a match...
      arrayOfEvents.push(value);
    }   
  })

  if (typeof results["d" + item.date] == "undefined") {
    results["d" + item] = {
      date: item,
      events: arrayOfEvents
    };
  }

});

{JSON.stringify(results, null, 4)}
```

Array

```
var dates = 
[
"01-06-2020",
"01-07-2020",
"01-08-2020",
"01-10-2020",
"02-04-2020"
]
```

Array of Objects

```
var arrayOfObjects =
[
{
    "title": "Group President",
    "id": "TpNY1SU_",
    "info": {
        "startDate": "01-06-2020"
    }
},
{
    "title": "TEST",
    "id": "cEpPxopz",
    "info": {
        "startDate": "01-07-2020"
    }
},
{
    "title": "Example",
    "id": "jnTMr_r7",
    "info": {
        "startDate": "01-07-2020"
    }
},
]
```

Desired (Not Working Result) getting `[]` when setting `results = []`

```
results = [
"d01-06-2020": {
    "date": "01-06-2020",
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "Group President",
            "id": "TpNY1SU_",
            "info": {
                "startDate": "01-06-2020"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"d01-07-2020": {
    "date": "01-07-2020",
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "TEST",
            "id": "cEpPxopz",
            "info": {
                "startDate": "01-07-2020"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Example",
            "id": "jnTMr_r7",
            "info": {
                "startDate": "01-07-2020"
            }
        }
    ]
},
]
```

Working Result when setting `results = {}`

```
results =  {
"d01-06-2020": {
    "date": "01-06-2020",
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "Group President",
            "id": "TpNY1SU_",
            "info": {
                "startDate": "01-06-2020"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"d01-07-2020": {
    "date": "01-07-2020",
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "TEST",
            "id": "cEpPxopz",
            "info": {
                "startDate": "01-07-2020"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Example",
            "id": "jnTMr_r7",
            "info": {
                "startDate": "01-07-2020"
            }
        }
    ]
},
}
```

Comment: Way too much information. Please read [mcve] for information about how to ask good questions with only the information required.

Comment: Reduced the Data down to minimal amount

Comment: @CharlieFish I've added a code sandbox thar shows exactly what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Because it's key value pair data so better to save data in object and use `Object.values`, `Object.keys` or `Object.entries` as per your requirement.

Here is solution using Es6 `flat()` and `Object.values`

```js
results = {
"d01-06-2020": {
    "date": "01-06-2020",
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "Group President",
            "id": "TpNY1SU_",
            "info": {
                "startDate": "Mon Jan 06 2020 14:03:03 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"d01-07-2020": {
    "date": "01-07-2020",
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "TEST",
            "id": "cEpPxopz",
            "info": {
                "startDate": "Tue Jan 07 2020 11:16:52 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Example",
            "id": "jnTMr_r7",
            "info": {
                "startDate": "Tue Jan 07 2020 11:22:24 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
            }
        }
    ]
},
}
let res = Object.values(results).map(a=>a.events);
let dates = res.flat().map(a=>a.info.startDate);

console.log(dates)
```

Comment: try using the codesandbox example, it will not render when its an array

Comment: i dont like the idea of object of objects, i would prefer to keep it an array of objects